# Navigation Issue angular and typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an issue with my navigation bar. I used ngRoute from AngularJs and I can't understand why all the links work wrong at click.

Here my code:

app.ts file:

```
module AnimalPlanet {

    export var app: angular.IModule;
    app= angular.module("mainAnimalPlanet",["ngRoute"]);


    app.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider:ng.route.IRouteProvider, $locationProvider:angular.ILocationProvider) => {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                    controller:"a"

                })
                .when('/pets', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/pets.html',
                    controller:"MenuItemCtrl"

                })
                .when('/ldAdoption', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/ldAdoption.html',
                    controller:"c"

                })
                .when('/111111', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html',
                    controller:"d"

                })
                .when('/impressum', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/impressum.html',
                    controller:"e"

                })
                .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                });


    }]);

}
```

menuItem.ts file:
    "use strict";

module AnimalPlanet {

```
export class MenuItemCtrl {
    names: any[];

    constructor(names) {
        this.names = [{
            name: "Main",
            slug: "main",
            active: true,
            link: "/"
        }, {
            name: "Pets",
            slug: "pets",
            active: false,
            link: "/pets"
        }, {
            name: "LDAdoption",
            slug: "ldAdoption",
            active: false,
            link: "/ldAdoption"
        }, {
            name: "Contact",
            slug: "contact",
            active: false,
            link: "/contact"
        }, {
            name: "Impressum",
            slug: "impressum",
            active: false,
            link: "/impressum"
        }];

    }

}
angular.module('mainAnimalPlanet',['ngRoute']).controller("MenuItemCtrl", ["$scope", MenuItemCtrl]);
```

}

Please help me!!! Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate this "all the links work wrong at click" a bit more?

Comment: when i click on a menu item , it show me in URL something like: http://localhost:8080/#/pets but the content isn't show.

Comment: Do you have an **ng-view** anywhere? It would be nice if you could share the html code too.

Comment: I solved the issues . I removed the class name and I used instead module.config. Thanks.